# What is the ultimate goal of hacking a webserver?

Tags: malware, webserver, password-cracking, web-hosting

Recently I noticed a lot of traffic generated by automated bots that were checking for vulnerabilities in my web server. They were mainly looking for ways to hack into plesk/wordpress which I don't even have running on the server.

Now my question is, what are hackers trying to accomplish by hacking the server. I mean, even IF they manage to hack into plesk and take over some sites for a day or two, I would still be able to hard-reset the whole server thus rendering their efforts useless again?

Why are they doing it? What's the catch?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ultimate goal? It heavily depends on the initiator of the attack, but here are some ideas:

Attacker interested in financial gains:

- It may be worth huge amounts of effort to target high traffic webservers/domains that enjoy a good reputation (The domain name is associated with a trustful service) and then apply phishing techniques (Credit cards, paypal, bitcoin credentials, ...) on the many visiting users. The users are very likely to submit such personal information, because the user feels safe.
- Integrate the server in a botnet: Servers have usually much more networking *power* then personal computers and can leverage a DDOS attack.
- Often financial information as credit cards or paypal billing addresses are stored on the webserver (or the database, that is also compromised by taking over a webserver)
- Interest in other valuable information such as user credentials or closed source applications that are valuable.
- Using the captured server as a means to hide traffic. Back in the day I used to install socks5 servers (Can also be implemented in PHP if no compiler is available) to proxify traffic.
- Using the compromised server to redirect traffic in order to exploit user agents. Javascript redirection to a attacking server with a exploit kit istalled like blackhole. This step might me as sophisticated as you wish: Only redirect clients that have specific plugins installed (Java, flash, silverlight), are a concrete User Agent (old, exploitable IE browser versions...)

Otherwise:

- Pure curiosity
- Just testing if you can take it over due to a self set intellectual challenge
- Defacing for political purposes (anonymous?)
- Vandalism (lulzsec)
- Use the web server as starting point for further attacks like:
- Privilege escalation (Can we gain root privs?)
- Are internal hosts/networks available from the server (Might be the case when the webserver also works as a reverse proxy)

There are many reasons. Hope you get the point.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Basically for financial gains it's just a long shot in most cases and it's the few that really have valuable things stored that keeps it going. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: "Long shots" are much less of a hindrance when you can fire hundreds of shots per second at little to no cost. There are a *lot* of wordpress sites out there, and if even one in a thousand is vulnerable, a minute's worth of scanning might yield several hits.

Comment: one in thousand? That success rate may hold for automated attacks, but coincidentally I audited around 5 wordpress plugins during the last year and they all have very nasty stored XSS combined with XSRF that lead to RCE. I'd guess one in five wordpress site can be taken over when attacking manually...

Comment: specifically for *webservers* I'd suggest the attacker interested in profit seem awfully prone to making it a phishing site for paypal/banking/etc - this should probably be top of the list.  To answer the OP's question, having a webserver for a few hours of a high-volume phishing campaign can turn a profit; won't matter if the server gets nuked, the creds often get posted elsewhere immediately.

Comment: @pacifist: Good point, I added it to the answer.

Comment: +1 the only thing I would add is the automated nature of these attempts. This activity is not (necessarily) directly some "hacker" (sic) but software which may not have a clear or discernible motive scanning and attacking systems that match patterns.

Comment: My laptop battery is down, I'll all it later. Seems like the DNS tunnel in this cafeteria consumes especially much power ;)

Answer (score 2):

The traffic you are experiencing is merely the result of automatic scans by bots that all servers connected to the Internet will experience.

The target of such attacks are the lowest common denominator of servers out there -- badly configured with default passwords or unpatched with announced exploitable vulnerabilities. It is very likely that a server compromised in such a fashion will be added to a botnet for sending out spam emails and other similar activities which can earn the botnet operator a nice profit.

*You* might notice if your server was compromised but the owner of a server that leaves it unpatched or with default passwords *probably* isn't going to be monitoring logs very often. Such a server will probably remain compromised for a very long period of time.

Comment: +1 thanks for answering! I accepted the other answer as it gave more insight in the various goals of the hacker. But I totally agree with the unpatched/botnet thing. However, how would one make money by sending spam mails? Would the sender also have a shady webshop somewhere, or would he hack bank accounts with it or anything like that?

Comment: @Hless Simple enough things like affiliate links or getting hired to send spam about certain topics. Renting out botnets for various activities are very profitable.